# Examples of good Java desktop applications

Tags: java, desktop-application

More of a wiki list/collection, I'm looking for a list of good Java desktop apps. I've added a couple below to get started. Please list the framework/widget toolkit being used if it's know as well.

Comment: Is this a programming question???

Comment: It gives an idea about the abilities of the language/JVM.

Comment: It would be great if everybody started putting up a picture of the app they mention. Also a link to the site the software can be found at.

Comment: It seems most Java desktop apps are for developers. Android apps are written on Java, but it seems that nowadays (2019) there are few Java desktop (PC) apps targeted at end users. Related reading: https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/3tozqi/why_is_java_desktop_considered_to_be_dead/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This use to be a good showcase for that.

[Swing Sightings at Sun](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/sightings)

Answer (score 37):

[IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html) (Swing)

Comment: I also thought jEdit was pretty nice, but once I tried IDEA, I have to say it has the most user-friendly UI (packed with powerful features) of the desktop Java apps I've seen.

Answer (score 25):

Eclipse (SWT)

Comment: Not pure java as it requires its own native library, SWT precisely.

Answer (score 18):

Netbeans (Swing)

Answer (score 18):

[**Azureus**](http://azureus.sourceforge.net/) (SWT; thanks Peter) (strictly for legal purposes, of course)

Comment: I've always admired how feature rich and smooth this app was.  Goes to show Java is very capable on the desktop.

Comment: "Please list the framework/widget toolkit" too.

Answer (score 16):

jEdit (Swing?)

Comment: I use jEdit extensively and it's a joy to work with. Slava Pestov and team did an outstanding job.

Answer (score 15):

jDiskReport

http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/

The best disk-space browser I've come across.

Answer (score 15):

**Sweet Home 3D:**

http://www.sweethome3d.eu/index.jsp

[image]
<sub>(source: [sweethome3d.eu](http://www.sweethome3d.eu/images/SweetHome3DSolaris.png))</sub>

Answer (score 13):

### [Mucommander](http://www.mucommander.com/)

[image: screenshot should be here]
<sub>(source: [mucommander.com](http://www.mucommander.com/screenshots/1.png))</sub>

Comment: That looks quite good to be Java :P

Answer (score 9):

SoapUI - http://www.soapui.org

Answer (score 9):

[Squirrel SQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/)

Answer (score 8):

On a gaming front Three Rings has done an awesome job with [Puzzle Pirates](http://www.puzzlepirates.com/). Pure Java and runs great.

Answer (score 7):

SQL Developer

Comment: I must agree with you, but sometimes, it's very buggy.

Comment: It is sometimes buggy and slow to startup (seems most Java desktop apps are). Which is why I've since switched to the Database Explorer plugin in Eclipse.

Comment: Last time I used SQL Developer (couple years ago) I found it really stable? Has it gotten worse recently?

Answer (score 7):

[Visual VM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) - Monitoring and performance analysis tool.

[image: visual vm screen shot]
<sub>(source: [java.net](https://java.net/projects/visualvm/content/images/monitor.jpg))</sub>

I love the charts it produces

Answer (score 5):

[Vuze](http://www.vuze.com/app?service=home) (formerly Azereus) is good, but my top recomendation that I've run across is [YourSQL](http://yoursql.ludit.it/). It's a fantastic little MySQL client for OS X and I used it for more than 1.5 years before I found out it was Java. It was very well done. None of that classic "slow unintegrated junk" many people associate with Java applications.

Answer (score 5):

[FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/) (Swing)

Answer (score 5):

A bit obscure, but [Go Grinder](http://gogrinder.sourceforge.net/) fits the description.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you like it.

Comment: Not a desktop application per se (it's a library), but Go-related: http://www.davidjarvis.ca/jigo

Answer (score 5):

[DB Visualizer](http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/)

Answer (score 4):

Kodak Digital Cinema System (and I don't just say that because I wrote about 1/3rd of it including most of the gui.)

Answer (score 4):

[XMind](http://www.xmind.net/), beautiful mind mapping software based on Eclipe RCP.

Answer (score 3):

The [Runescape](http://runescape.com) game is the only Java application (it has a desktop client in Windows) that I use which isn't an IDE/Editor/Profiler.

Answer (score 3):

SmartSVN, SmartCVS

Answer (score 3):

[FreeCol](http://freecol.sf.net/), an open source clone of the classic Sid Meier game, Colonization.

Answer (score 3):

[Spark Messenger](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/index.jsp)

Answer (score 3):

[JOSM](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/) is the most popular [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Main_Page) editor and is written in Swing.

Answer (score 2):

Maple (Swing)

Had to work a lot with Maple the last week. It's such a nice and powerful tool, I first couldn't believe that it was developed with Swing and Java :)

Answer (score 2):

**Jalbum**

http://jalbum.net/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Aerith](https://aerith.dev.java.net/) (Swing + OpenGL) It is kind of experimental though.

Answer (score 1):

RSSOwl news feed reader - http://www.rssowl.org/

Answer (score 1):

**Genj** (Genealogy)

http://genj.sourceforge.net/

[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://genj.sourceforge.net/forum/download/file.php?id=54))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[GWT designer (Java UI) designer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/index.html) for eclipse

Answer (score 1):

[Violet UM](http://alexdp.free.fr/violetumleditor/page.php)L looks like an excellent diagramming tool.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Getting Things Done](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Things_Done) implementation [ThinkingRock](http://www.trgtd.com.au)